# Render image doesn'y match my camera perspective

Tags: rendering, camera

Recently I'm trying to make this backroom footage, but it seems like that my render output have some differences to my camera view in layout mode.

The wall buffer seems to disappear in the output, the viewing angle is also different from the camera perspective view, the carpet's texture also seems doesn't match as well.

Since I'm new in blender, I've no idea where to change these settings.

This is my blender file. Thanks alot!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E_Kkdq1SyBdq4EYTU5FPEwU2_0Ltsl3Y/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check your *Outliner*, you have some objects that are disabled in viewport but enabled in render (I can't see any difference in the perspective though):

[image]

Comment: Wow! I completely forget that I left those two object in my file. Thanks alot!